# GAS/ Javascript: Save API as a response perform calculations on them and if they meet condition send emails

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am working on a personal project to try and stretch limits of a 10K ft project management systems API and being new to GAS or Javascript I will appreciate help on the code I am trying to do. The API documentation for this can be found at https://github.com/10Kft/10kft-api.

Using time entries and users endpoints,  I would like to loop through all users and get their time entries for a particular time frame. I would like these data saved as an array and the time entries (hours) added to get totals. If for some reason, a particular user time entries are below 3hrs, an email is sent to the user notifying him/her to complete timesheets. I got lost at some point. Here is the code I have so far: Anyone good at this, please help.

```
function getTime() {
    var range = [5323, 9626, 4998];
    var user = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {

        var auth = 'xxxxxxxx=';

        var from = '2020-01-08'
        var to = '2020-01-09'
        var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + range[i] + '/time_entries?from=' + from + '&to=' + to + '&auth=' + auth;

        var options = {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + auth
            }
        };
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
        Logger.log(response.getContentText());
        var user_data = response.getContentText();
        user_data.foreach(function(data) {
        var total_hours = sum.reduce(data.hours);
        })

        var array = [];

        return array;
    }}
```

Comment: Could you provide some dummy data that would exemplify the data received in your ```response``` var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You'll need to parse the response.
2. Loop through user entries.
3. Aggregate them based on user id.
4. Loop through aggregation.
5. Conditionally send email.

Something like this :

var submitted_time_entries = {};

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var time_entries = response.data;

time_entries.foreach(function(time_entry) {
    if (time_entry.user_id in submitted_time_entries) {
        submitted_time_entries[time_entry.user_id] += time_entry.hours;
    } else {
        submitted_time_entries[time_entry.user_id] = time_entry.hours;
    }
});

submitted_time_entries.forEach(function(user_id) {
    if (submitted_time_entries[user_id] < 3) {
        //send mail
    }
});
```